# Retrieving a List of network interfaces in node.js (ioctl SIOCGIFCONF)

Tags: javascript, node.js, interface, v8, ioctl

I'm new to node and am hacking together a node application utilizing [node_pcap](https://github.com/mranney/node_pcap) to capture packet data and do interesting things with it.  One of the inputs to capturing data is the network interface to listen on, i.e. "eth0".

I thought it would be really great if I could programmatically look up the available interfaces on the system and present them to the user of the program and allow them to pick which interface to listen on.  In C, I would use [ioctl](http://kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) (or ioctlsocket with winsock) using SIOCGIFCONF.

My question is, does there currently exist a mechanism to do this in node?   I've searched quite a bit and haven't arrived to any such solution.

If this functionality does not currently exist,  I would assume I'd be able to write a Module binding in C/C++ using ioctl to accomplish this.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update valid as of Node 13.7.0**

This has been renamed since this answer was submitted. It is now just `networkInterfaces()` like this:

```
require('os').networkInterfaces()
```

Or probably preferably like this:

```
import { networkInterfaces } from 'os';

const interfaces = networkInterfaces();
```

New docs url: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/os.html#os_os_networkinterfaces

**Original answer**

As of Node.js 0.6.0 you have

```
require('os').getNetworkInterfaces()
```

See http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/os.html#os.getNetworkInterfaces

Comment: Excellent!  This is exactly what I need.  I'll need to make sure I look through the API docs next time before I ask a question like this.  Thank you for answering :).

Comment: Note that this does not show any interfaces which do not have a connection since boot. Meaning if you have several interfaces, say `eth0`, `eth1` where only `eth0` has ever been connected. This method will only show `eth0` and not `eth1`.

Comment: Virtual interfaces created by hand do show, like `enp5s0` and `enp5s0:1`.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/498

Answer (score 1):

If you want to list only the name of interfaces :

```
 Object.keys(os.getNetworkInterfaces())
  // [ 'lo0', 'en0', 'en3', 'awdl0' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

os.networkInterfaces() method returns an object containing only network interfaces that have been assigned a network addresS but if we want all network card in machine we can use this method

```
var shell = require('shelljs'); 

 var interfaceCard = shell.ls('/sys/class/net');
```

this interfaceCard has list of all network interfaces

output will be

```
[ 'eth0',
'eth1',
'lo',
 stdout: 'eth0\neth1\nlo\n',
  stderr: null,
code: 0,
cat: [Function: bound ],
exec: [Function: bound ],
grep: [Function: bound ],
head: [Function: bound ],
 sed: [Function: bound ],
sort: [Function: bound ],
 tail: [Function: bound ],
  to: [Function: bound ],
 toEnd: [Function: bound ],
 uniq: [Function: bound ] ]

 interfaceCard=interfaceCard.stdout.split('\n');

 interfaceCard = eth0, eth1, lo
```